# Error 52 bad file name or number, after filename change

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

Our org just migrated from SharePoint 2013 to 2016. Now we have an excel macro that is throwing the Error 52 Bad file name or number when trying to perform a file action on a SharePoint file. The file name now has to have a url parameter at the end of it.

I have included the snippet below with original and new paths, the FileDateTime function line is throwing Error 52.

Code Snippet:

```
Sub ACQUIRE_LATEST_DATA()
Dim myBook As Workbook, RawRep As Workbook
Dim RawTab As Worksheet
Dim fdate As String

    
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set RawTab = myBook.Sheets("RawReport")
Set ListsTab = myBook.Sheets("Lists")

'Original Path
Set RawRep = Workbooks.Open("http://[pathToSharePointSite]/Starters/NewStarterMasterReport.csv")
'New Path
Set RawRep = Workbooks.Open("https://restricted.[pathToSharePointSite]/Starters/NewStarterMasterReport.csv?d=w215fc66a166c403587b89b26912a7613")
    
RawTab.Cells.Clear
With RawRep.Sheets("NewStarterMasterReport").UsedRange
     RawTab.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With
'RawTab.Columns(23).NumberFormat = "(""###"")""###""-""####"
'RawTab.Columns(24).NumberFormat = "(""###"")""###""-""####"
'RawTab.Columns(25).NumberFormat = "(""###"")""###""-""####"
'RawTab.Columns(26).NumberFormat = "(""###"")""###""-""####"

RawRep.Close

With RawTab.Range("A1:AO1")
.Interior.Color = ListsTab.Cells(1, 3).Interior.Color
.WrapText = ListsTab.Cells(1, 3).WrapText
.Font.Bold = ListsTab.Cells(1, 3).Font.Bold
.Font.Color = ListsTab.Cells(1, 3).Font.Color
End With

RawTab.Cells.RemoveDuplicates (12)

'Original Path    
fdate = FileDateTime("\\[pathToSharePointSite]\Starters\NewStarterMasterReport.csv")
'New Path (THIS IS BRAKING THROWING ERROR 52)
fdate = FileDateTime("\\restricted.[pathToSharePointSite]\Starters\NewStarterMasterReport.csv?d=w215fc66a166c403587b89b26912a7613")

ListsTab.Cells(2, 4).Value = fdate
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe try smething like `FileDateTime(Split("\\restricted.[pathToSharePointSite]\Starters\NewStarterMasterReport.csv?d=w215fc66a166c403587b89b26912a7613", "?")(0))`

Answer (score 1):

Alright it's been figured out. The url parameter is not needed at all which was throwing error 52.

The new 2016 server has SSL which 2013 did not. So the appropriate network path needed '@ssl' included:

```
fdate = FileDateTime("\\restricted.[pathToSharePointSite]@ssl\Starters\NewStarterMasterReport.csv")
```